# hasClass on current slideshow?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm using this plugin: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#basic-usage
and I'm looking for a way to change menu class if image has current class.

If the current image in the slideshow has class bright I want to addClass bright to menu.
I'm using this code:

```
 jQuery(window).load(function() 
 if ($('#the-img').hasClass('dark')) {
 $('#widget-menu').addClass('menu-dark');
}
 });
```

This is giving my menu class menu-dark.

But how to do when I want it to change if img has the class bright if is current?
Would be very thankful for an answer.

The site that I'm working on is:
http://mlido.se/site/case/luxit/

Answer (score 0):

Magnus, what is the function that slides your images, can you show the code?

The general idea to solve your problem is to check image class in animation complete callback.

You need to define a function like:

```
function checkImageClass () {
    $('#widget-menu').removeClass('menu-dark').removeClass('menu-bright');
    if ($('#the-img').hasClass('dark')) {
        $('#widget-menu').addClass('menu-dark');
    } else {
        $('#widget-menu').addClass('menu-bright');
    }
}
```

and then, where your animation is defined add the complete callback like this.

```
$(your-selector).animate({
    left : ...
}, {
    complete : checkImageClass
});
```

I can't find the animation control code on your site. If you post your animation code here I will try to update it according to my advice.

For additional info [see jquery animate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)